# Android Studio: How to add a definition to a file

Tags: android, xml, resources, definition

Android studio beginner here. My professor is telling me to change the res/values/strings.xml in my application. The purpose of this is to add a Color definition to the file and then tells me to press an "Add" button. However, I'm having trouble actually accessing the same window he is...here is the window:

[image: Desired IDE]

What I see when opening the strings.xml file is this:
[image]

There are no buttons for me to actually add a definition. I tried playing around with the strings.xml file by right clicking the file, but nothing really looks like anything I want.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> My professor is telling me to change the res/values/strings.xml in my application.

Here you mention that you want to change the strings using `Add` button. In that case, you can do it as follows:

- Click on `Open Editor` on the top right when your `strings.xml` is open.
  [image]
- Then you will see this new Window. Use `+` key to add a new string resource. 
  [image]

Your professor might have a different Android Studio version. This is how it shows in Android Studio `2.3.3` version.

> The purpose of this is to add a Color definition to the file ...

Here you mention that you want to change the color definitions. If that's the case, you need to change in `colors.xml`. If a file is not there, then create one in `values` folder and add `<color name="color_name">#HEX_VALUE</color>`. Then you can reference the color from Java or XML file.

Comment: Thank you! Your second explanation was the one I was looking for. I don't know why he wanted to put the new Color in strings.xml file, but I did what you recommended and opened the colors.xml instead. Is there any difference in putting it to the strings.xml as opposed to the colors.xml file?

Comment: It seems like from older version UI snapshot in your question that one can add any resource from there. Maybe he wanted to add a color resource using same UI.

Answer (score 1):

Just add another entry in your strings.xml file corresponding to what your requirement is, and save the file.

For example:

```
<resources>
    <string name="app_name">Temperature Converter</string>
    <string name="new_string_name">new_string_value</string>
</resources>
```